# FluentNHibernate: mapping child collection with discriminator

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, discriminator

Viewing my object with nested collection don't throw an error, but when trying to **save** the entity i had an error

```
    [IndexOutOfRangeException: Invalid index 15 for SqlParameterCollection with Count=15.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.RangeCheck(Int32 index) +5343807
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.GetParameter(Int32 index) +19
   System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index) +10
   NHibernate.Type.Int64Type.Set(IDbCommand rs, Object value, Int32 index) +60
   NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, Object value, Int32 index) +414
   NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value, Int32 index, Boolean[] settable, ISessionImplementor session) +62
   NHibernate.Type.ManyToOneType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value, Int32 index, Boolean[] settable, ISessionImplementor session) +122
   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement, ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index) +344

[PropertyValueException: Error dehydrating property value for PravUprav.Classes.Entities.ClaimCaseInstanceFI.Decision]
   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement, ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index) +503
   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session) +2013
   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.UpdateOrInsert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session) +335
   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Int32[] dirtyFields, Boolean hasDirtyCollection, Object[] oldFields, Object oldVersion, Object obj, Object rowId, ISessionImplementor session) +1898
   NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.Execute() +737
   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable) +39
   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list) +128
   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions() +48
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session) +241
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event) +179
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush() +295
   NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit() +189
   Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager.DoCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status) in c:\_prj\spring-net\src\Spring\Spring.Data.NHibernate\Data\NHibernate\HibernateTransactionManager.cs:561

[DataIntegrityViolationException: Error dehydrating property value for PravUprav.Classes.Entities.ClaimCaseInstanceFI.Decision]
   Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager.DoCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status) in c:\_prj\spring-net\src\Spring\Spring.Data.NHibernate\Data\NHibernate\HibernateTransactionManager.cs:577
```

Error:

```
Error dehydrating property value for
```

says that I mapped property twice or DataTypes of entities properties incorrect, but i checked and not found error in my code.

Entity with collection:

```
public class ClaimCase
{
    private IList<ClaimCaseInstance> _claimCaseInstances;
    public virtual IList<ClaimCaseInstance> ClaimCaseInstances
    {
       get { return _claimCaseInstances ?? (_claimCaseInstances = new List<ClaimCaseInstance>()); }
          set { _claimCaseInstances = value; }
     }
}
```

Mapping for entity:

```
public sealed class ClaimCaseMap : ClassMap<ClaimCase>
{
   public ClaimCaseMap()
      {
         Table("ClaimCase");
         Id(x => x.Id);                
         HasMany(x => x.ClaimCaseInstances).Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
       }
 }
```

ClaimCaseInstance entity:

```
public abstract class ClaimCaseInstance
{
    public virtual ClaimCase ClaimCase { get; set; }
    public virtual DicList Result { get; set; }
}
```

Child classes:

```
public class ClaimCaseInstanceFI : ClaimCaseInstance
{
    public virtual DicList Decision { get; set; }
}

public class ClaimCaseInstanceAI : ClaimCaseInstance
{
}
```

Mappings:

```
public sealed class ClaimCaseInstanceMap : ClassMap<ClaimCaseInstance>
{
    public ClaimCaseInstanceMap()
    {
        Table("ClaimCaseInstances");
        Id(x => x.Id);            
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("InstanceType");

        References(x => x.ClaimCase);
        References(x => x.Result);
    }
}

public sealed class ClaimCaseInstanceFIMap : SubclassMap<ClaimCaseInstanceFI>
{
    public ClaimCaseInstanceFIMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue((int)CourtTypes.Firts);
        References(x => x.Decision);
    }
}

public sealed class ClaimCaseInstanceAIMap : SubclassMap<ClaimCaseInstanceAI>
{
    public ClaimCaseInstanceAIMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue((int)CourtTypes.Appeals);
    }
}
```

CourtTypes:

```
public enum CourtTypes
{
    First = 5,
    Appeals = 6
}
```

`DicList` reference mapping by convention `ForeignKeyConversion` as `instance.Property.Name + "ID"` and it's work fine.

Error only occurs when saving `ClaimCase` after editing a field `Decision`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've identified the source of the problem.
Using the great tool [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/%22dotPeek%22) (thanks @SergSW for the tip) as [symbol server](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/webhelp10/Using_product_as_a_Symbol_Server.html) and [debug](http://hmemcpy.com/2014/07/how-to-debug-anything-with-visual-studio-and-jetbrains-dotpeek-v1-2/)

```
NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate()
```

i found that count of Updated fields in sql statement are not equal count

```
entityMetamodel.PropertySpan
```

Some of the fields in the array `entityMetamodel.Properties` were present twice.

```
public sealed class ClaimCaseInstanceMap : ClassMap<ClaimCaseInstance>
    {
        public ClaimCaseInstanceMap()
        {
            Table("ClaimCaseInstances");

            DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("InstanceType");

            Id(x => x.Id);  
            References(x => x.ClaimCase);
            Map(x => x.FilingDate);
            References(x => x.Result);
            Map(x => x.PriceResult);
            Map(x => x.ExpenseResult);
            Map(x => x.Comment);
        }
    }
```

SubClass:

```
public sealed class ClaimCaseInstanceFIMap : SubclassMap<ClaimCaseInstanceFI>
{
    public ClaimCaseInstanceFIMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue((int)CourtType.Firts);

        Id(x => x.Id);  
        Map(x => x.Price);
        Map(x => x.Expense);
        References(x => x.Decision);
        References(x => x.Determination);
        Map(x => x.DeterminationDate);
        Map(x => x.CourtDateAct);
        Map(x => x.PriceResult);
        Map(x => x.ExpenseResult);
        Map(x => x.CounterClaimDate);
        Map(x => x.Comment);
    }
}
```

As you can see, this properties: `Comment`, `ExpenseResult`, `PriceResult`.

I've not described the mapping for all the fields in my question, it's my error, sorry for that and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
[IndexOutOfRangeException: Invalid index 15 for SqlParameterCollection with Count=15.]
```

Looks like that there is a problem with generated SQL request. 
Can you show the SQL statment for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Batch commands:
command 0:

Batch commands:

command 0:UPDATE ClaimCase SET CreatedDate = @p0, IsHidden = @p1, InnerNumber = @p2, OdpNumber = @p3, DocumentsDeliveryDate = @p4, CourtPostDate = @p5, IncomingClaimDate = @p6, DisputeDescription = @p7, LawsuitNumber = @p8, TotalPriceResult = @p9, Note = @p10, CourtSector = @p11, CaseClosed = @p12, IsBankrupt = @p13, BankruptDate = @p14, CreatedBy = @p15, CaseCategoryID = @p16, ClaimDirection = @p17, ForeignCuratorID = @p18, InnerContractCuratorID = @p19, DisputeID = @p20, CourtID = @p21, CourtDistrictID = @p22, MunicipalContractID = @p23, BelongToDepartmentID = @p24 WHERE Id = @p25;@p0 = 06.05.2014 9:59:56 [Type: DateTime (0)], @p1 = False [Type: Boolean (0)], @p2 = 'БИС-7/2014' [Type: String (4000)], @p3 = '5345345' [Type: String (4000)], @p4 = 15.05.2014 0:00:00 [Type: DateTime (0)], @p5 = 17.05.2014 0:00:00 [Type: DateTime (0)], @p6 = 08.05.2014 0:00:00 [Type: DateTime (0)], @p7 = 'предмет спора.' [Type: String (4000)], @p8 = '534534' [Type: String (4000)], @p9 = 100,00 [Type: Decimal (0)], @p10 = NULL [Type: String (4000)], @p11 = NULL [Type: String (4000)], @p12 = False [Type: Boolean (0)], @p13 = False [Type: Boolean (0)], @p14 = NULL [Type: DateTime (0)], @p15 = 7026 [Type: Int64 (0)], @p16 = 23 [Type: Int64 (0)], @p17 = 28 [Type: Int64 (0)], @p18 = 7026 [Type: Int64 (0)], @p19 = 19 [Type: Int64 (0)], @p20 = 14 [Type: Int64 (0)], @p21 = 35 [Type: Int64 (0)], @p22 = 86 [Type: Int64 (0)], @p23 = 2 [Type: Int64 (0)], @p24 = 2027 [Type: Int64 (0)], @p25 = 12347 [Type: Int64 (0)]

And next:

```
Could not synchronize database state with session

NHibernate.PropertyValueException: Error dehydrating property value for PravUprav.Classes.Entities.ClaimCaseInstanceFI.Decision ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Недопустимый индекс 16 для SqlParameterCollection с Count=16.
```